# Proving that $\ln(1+x)$ converges using $R_n(x)$

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find for what values of $x$, Taylor's series of $\ln(1+x)$ converges about $x=0$.

We have:
$$\ln(1+x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{x^2}{2!}f''(0)+...+R_n(x)$$

Where $$R_n(x)=\frac{f^n(c)}{n!}x^n$$ where $c \in (0, x)$

Now we have the $n$th derivative of $\ln(1+x)$ as:
$$f^n(c)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(1+c)^n}$$

Now for convergence we have:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}|R_n(x)| \to 0$$

Now since $0<c<x$ we have:
$$|R_n(x)|<\frac{x^n}{n} \to 0$$ only when $-1<x<1$ and diverges else.
is my proof correct?

Comment: Not that simple.  $\log(2) = 1 - (1/2) + (1/3) - (1/4) + \cdots - \cdots$.

Comment: Ya i know about $x=1$ case. But is it correct atleast for $-1<x<1$?

Comment: Yes, it certainly is.